# Creating SVG graphics using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, graphics, svg

How can I create SVG graphics using JavaScript?

Do all browsers support SVG?

Comment: After 2 years svg development can say, that it nice thing, but without full support from all major browser it doesn't worse to be used. If you start a new app, choose another format instead.

Comment: Anyone reading this question and answers, beware that much has evolved since the question was asked back in 2009 and SVG is now supported by all major browsers natively (don't need polyfills)!

Comment: Here is link to see actual supported browsers. http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg It's definetly save to use svg nowdays.

Answer (score 31):

Have a look at [this list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support) about which browsers support SVG. It also provides links to more details in the footnotes. Firefox for example supports basic SVG, but at the moment lacks most animation features.

A tutorial about how to create SVG objects using Javascript can be found [here](http://softwareas.com/ajaxjavascript-8-ways-to-create-graphics-on-the-fly):

```
var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var svgDocument = evt.target.ownerDocument;
var shape = svgDocument.createElementNS(svgns, "circle");
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", 25);
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", 25);
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "r",  20);
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "green");
```

Comment: any solution for firefox yet?

Comment: You should really explain `evt`.  See themadmax's anwer for a solution that works.

Answer (score 25):

### This answer is from 2009.  Now a community wiki in case anybody cares to bring it up-to-date.

IE needs a plugin to display SVG.  Most common is the one available for download by Adobe; however, Adobe no longer supports or develops it.  Firefox, Opera, Chrome, Safari, will all display basic SVG fine but will run into quirks if advanced features are used, as support is incomplete.  Firefox has no support for declarative animation.

SVG elements can be created with javascript as follows:

```
// "circle" may be any tag name
var shape = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
// Set any attributes as desired
shape.setAttribute("cx", 25);
shape.setAttribute("cy", 25);
shape.setAttribute("r",  20);
shape.setAttribute("fill", "green");
// Add to a parent node; document.documentElement should be the root svg element.
// Acquiring a parent element with document.getElementById() would be safest.
document.documentElement.appendChild(shape);
```

The [SVG specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/) describes the DOM interfaces for all SVG elements.  For example, the SVGCircleElement, which is created above, has `cx`, `cy`, and `r` attributes for the center point and radius, which can be directly accessed. These are the SVGAnimatedLength attributes, which have a `baseVal` property for the normal value, and an `animVal` property for the animated value. Browsers at the moment are not reliably supporting the `animVal` property. `baseVal` is an SVGLength, whose value is set by the `value` property.

Hence, for script animations, one can also set these DOM properties to control SVG. The following code should be equivalent to the above code:

```
var shape = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
shape.cx.baseVal.value = 25;
shape.cy.baseVal.value = 25;
shape.r.baseVal.value = 20;
shape.setAttribute("fill", "green");
document.documentElement.appendChild(shape);
```

Comment: This is no longer true and this answer should be updated or removed.

Answer (score 17):

To do it cross-browser, I strongly recommend [RaphaelJS](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael).  It has a hell of a good API and does VML in IE, that can't understand SVG.

Answer (score 8):

All modern browsers except IE support SVG

Here is a tutorial that provides step by step guide on how to work with SVG using javascript:

> [SVG Scripting with JavaScript Part 1: Simple Circle](http://blazingcloud.net/2010/09/17/svg-scripting-with-javascript-part-1-simple-circle/)

Like [Boldewyn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034712/creating-svg-graphics-using-javascript/1040307#1040307) has said already if you want

> To do it cross-browser, I strongly recommend RaphaelJS: [rapaheljs.com](http://raphaeljs.com)

Although right now I feel the size of the library is too large. It has many great features some of which you might not need.

Comment: "All modern browsers except IE"? :)

Comment: No IE version is modern. In the case of SVG, IE (through v11) does not support SMIL, so forget any interesting animations!

Answer (score 7):

I like [**jQuery SVG**](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html) library very much. It helps me every time I need to manipulate with SVG. It really facilitate the work with SVG from JavaScript.

Answer (score 6):

I found no complied answer so to create circle and add to svg try this:

```js
var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var svg = document.getElementById('svg');
var shape = document.createElementNS(svgns, "circle");
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", 25);
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", 25);
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "r",  20);
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "green");
svg.appendChild(shape);
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="100" height="100"></svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

No not all browsers support SVG.  I believe IE needs a plugin to use them.   Since svg is just an xml document, JavaScript can create them.  I am not certain about loading it into the browser though.  I haven't tried that.

This link has information about javascript and svg:

http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/SVGAnimations.htm

Answer (score 2):

There's a jQuery plugin that allows you to manipulate SVG via Javascript:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/svg

From its intro:

> Supported natively in Firefox, Opera,
>   and Safari and via the Adobe SVG
>   viewer or Renesis player in IE, SVG
>   lets you display graphics within your
>   Web pages. Now you can easily drive
>   the SVG canvas from your JavaScript
>   code.

Answer (score 2):

[You can use d3.js. It is easy to use and powerful.](http://d3js.org/)

`D3.js` is a JavaScript library for manipulating documents based on data. D3 helps you bring data to life using HTML, SVG and CSS.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple libraries on SVG graphics using Javascript like: Snap, Raphael, D3. Or you can directly interface the SVG with plain javascript.

Currently all latest versions of the browsers support SVG v1.1. SVG v2.0 is in Working Draft and too early to use it.

This article shows how to interact with SVG using Javascript and has reference to links for browser support. [Interfacing with SVG](http://tumba.solutions/blog/svg)

Answer (score 1):

## innerHTML

Currently all major browsers [support svg](https://caniuse.com/#search=svg). Create svg in JS is very simple
(currently `innerHTML=...` is [quite fast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51140250/860099))

```
element.innerHTML = `
    <svg viewBox="0 0 400 100" >
      <circle id="circ" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="red" />
    </svg>
`;
```

```js
box.innerHTML = `
  <svg viewBox="0 0 400 100" >
    <circle id="circ" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="red" />
  </svg>
`;


function decRadius() {
  r=circ.getAttribute('r');
  circ.setAttribute('r',r*0.5);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="decRadius()">Decrease radius</button>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

IE 9 now supports basic SVG 1.1. It was about time, although IE9 still is far behind Google Chrome and Firefox SVG support.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/hh410107.aspx

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to build your SVG stuff piece by piece in JS, then don't just use `createElement()`, those won't draw, use this instead:

```
var ci = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
```