# Javascript createElement no end tag

Tags: javascript, document, createelement

I'm trying to use document.createElement('circle') to work with svgs but Chrome creates a end tag to circle giving

```
<circle></circle>
```

which results of an error.
How can I create an element without an ending that?

Comment: Why don't you want an end tag?

Comment: Because the end tag causes chrome to not display the circle...

Comment: End tags are never optional (unless you are using self-closing tag syntax) for XML elements … and noting will generate an end tag when you use `createElement`. The parser turns an XML document into a DOM (where there are only nodes, not tags). You can manipulate it all you like. If you turn it back into an XML document, **then** you get tags.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this article

[SVG Scripting with JavaScript Part 1: Simple Circle](http://blazingcloud.net/2010/09/17/svg-scripting-with-javascript-part-1-simple-circle/)

The method you're looking for is:

```
var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
```

Edit: Credit where credit is due

[Stackoverflow: Creating SVG graphics using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034712/creating-svg-graphics-using-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

try using `document.createElementNS`:

```
var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","circle");
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to use :

```
document.createElementNS('circle')
```