# dynamically created SVG element not displaying

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to draw an SVG rectangle with pure JavaScript. It's not showing up.

But when I run `document.getElementById('rect1')` in the the browser console, the rectangle element exists. And when I copy and paste the HTML from the console into the HTML file, the rectangle displays properly. So it seems as though the correct code is being added to the document, but the element isn't being displayed.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <svg id="test" width="500" height="500">
          <!-- code copied from browser console works 
          <rect x="30" y="60" width="50" height="80" style="stroke:#000000; fill:none;" id="rect1">
         </rect> -->
     </svg>

      <svg id="main" width="500" height="500"></svg>
    </div>
    <script src="./src/shapes.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function addSvgElement() {
    var rect = document.createElement("rect");
    rect.setAttribute('x', 30);
    rect.setAttribute('y', 60);
    rect.setAttribute('width', 50);
    rect.setAttribute('height', 80);
    rect.setAttribute('style', "stroke:#000000; fill:none;");
    rect.id = "rect1";
    var svg = document.getElementById('main');
    svg.appendChild(rect);
}

addSvgElement(); // adds correct code, but element doesn't show up
```

Comment: looks like it works...http://jsfiddle.net/fpG4Z/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating SVG graphics using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034712/creating-svg-graphics-using-javascript)

Comment: @sfletche Sorry, I didn't make it clear that the code in the HTML file that was generating the rectangle was copied from the browser console and pasted into the document for debugging. I wanted to generate the rectangle dynamically, though.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`document.createElement("rect");` will create an unknown HTML DOM element. You have to use the correct namespace to create an SVG DOM element.

```
var rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
```