# Create orphan tag in jQuery without plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I tried creating new tags using jQuery and appending using `$("<div></div>")`.
But I want to create some XML elements which are orphan tags (which has no ending tags).

When I tried to create such tags, using

```
$("<column/>")
```

It is creating

```
<column></column>
```

and I am expecting `<column />`.

How can I do this without any jQuery plugin?
I am adding some attributes for it after creating that element.

Comment: Check the question once you post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, I found following answer.

Its little difficult to create XML document using jQUery, but with JavaScript, it is very easy.

> Create instance of xml document.

```
var createXMLDocument=function(){
 var _doc,perser;
 if(window.DOMParser){
   parser=new DOMParser();
   _doc=parser.parseFromString("<doc></doc>","application/xml");
 }else{
   _doc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
   doc.async="false";
   _doc.loadXML("<doc></doc>");
 }
 return _doc
}
```

> Create elements.

```
var xml=new createXMLDocument();
var _columns=xml.createElement("columns");
var _column=xml.createElement("column");
```

> Attach it to XML main document.

```
_columns.appendChild(_column);
xml.firstChild.appendChild(_columns);
```

> It will create xml like this;

```
<doc>
  <columns>
    <column/>    // This is what I needed
  </columns>
</doc>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) says:

> When the parameter has a single tag, such as `$('<img />')` or `$('<a></a>')`, jQuery creates the element using the native JavaScript `createElement()` function.

So it is the browser that decides whether the tag is a self-closing tag or there should be a closing tag.

If you are definitely sure that it doesn't have a self closing tag, like the `<circle />` element and it has a specification, then you need to use:

```
var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
```

Reference: [Creating SVG graphics using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034712/creating-svg-graphics-using-javascript)

Comment: And createElement cannot be used to create SVG tags.

Comment: @praveen Kumar, I am using $("<column/>") but still it is creating ending tag, here is what I did. https://jsfiddle.net/dlinx/7qvgztLa/

Comment: @LaxmikantDange It is not you, but it is the browser that makes it close tag.

Comment: There is no semantic difference between `<column></column>` and `<column/>`. A UA is free to display it in either fashion.

Comment: @RobertLongson Its not difference for browser but I am creating xml which I am going to export for another software which consider it as difference

Comment: @LaxmikantDange Go file a bug report on that software then. Or fix it to work correctly.

Comment: @RobertLongson Ha ha ha... That's rude buddy!

Comment: @PraveenKumar That software is buggy and should not do that. He's fixing the wrong thing. Why is pointing that out rude?

Comment: The conclusion is that <column></column> and <column/> are both valid and identical as far as XML is concerned. An XML parser is not allowed to distinguish between the two cases. There's no way to create one of them specifically.

Comment: @RobertLongson Just said it is like straight into face. I was sarcastic buddy, and you weren't rude!!! Don't take it seriously!