# Is there a way to add DOM element as marker for google map js api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I was able to find an archived library with "RichMarker.js" which solves my problem but is there any new or better solution to this problem.

**What I am trying to do**

[Marker Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIv4R.png)

I need to display different type of info boxes for each of the semi-circle when clicked and the data in the marker is dynamic. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use `.svg`

To personalize at best custom markers with dynamic shape/color/textContent... you can draw `.svg` object in javascript (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034712/creating-svg-graphics-using-javascript) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725288/svg-text-inside-rect)).

After, you just need to set it like an image

```
iconForMarker = {url: iconSvg, size:new google.maps.Size(20, 20)};
let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: gMap,
    icon: iconForMarker,
    // optimized false only if you have 200 or more markers  
    optimized: false
 });
```

You can update your image at anytime by doing

```
newIconForMarker = {url: newIconSvg, size:new google.maps.Size(20, 20)};
marker.setOptions({'icon':newIconForMarker });
```

## Use `canvas`

You can also use 2d canvas (see [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/130479) from stackexchange)

```
let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.canvas.width = 38 * scale;
context.canvas.height = 46 * scale;
let sources = {
    pin: createPin(colorPin, scale),
    photo: dataPhoto                
};
loadImages(sources, function(images) {
    context.drawImage(images.pin, 0, 0);
    context.drawImage(images.photo, 5 * scale, 3 * scale);
    // creating a marker
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: null,
        icon: canvas.toDataURL()
    });
    callback(marker);                   
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This is one of the solutions I was able to dig out on google. Fredik title's approach. It uses jQuery, but I think your could rewrite it as js

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {

    if (!this.hovercardInitialized) {

        var markerInDOM = $('div[title="' + this.title + '"]').get(0);

        // do whatever you want with the DOM element

        this.hovercardInitialized = true;
    }

});
```