# JS: How to dynamically insert text into a SPAN?

Tags: javascript, html

Without using any JavaScript frameworks, how do I dynamically change the text within a `SPAN` element.

I know how to do this with a `DIV`, it would be the following:

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = '...'
```

What's the equivalent of this for a `SPAN` element?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`getElementById()` do exactly as the name implies: get an element with id attribute equals to argument; so, if you have an span named "mySpan", your code should be:

```
document.getElementById('mySpan').innerHTML = '...'
```

Answer (score 12):

`innerHTML` will work but it can be dangerous in some situations if you don't know what you're doing. It can insert HTML tags, not just text, possibly opening you up to XSS attacks etc.

The `textContent` with `innerText` fallback that some have proposed is a better idea as you don't have to worry about script injection, etc.

If you don't have to support IE8 and earlier, use `textContent` with no fallback. IE9 and later support `textContent`.

Comment: This should be much higher as it is a highly detailed answer to a general problem, not a use case specific to the OP.

Comment: It's a little confusing though. A small example would be clearer.

Answer (score 5):

That specific technique works for any element, though the caveat on using it on elements such as divs is that it will replace inner elements and not only text.

If you only want to replace the text you can do so by:

```
function replaceText( el, str ) {
    el.textContent ? el.textContent = str : el.innerText = str;
}

replaceText( spanReference, 'blah' )
```

Answer (score 0):

The safest, most common way is:

```
document.querySelector(".element").innerText = "My text here";
```

If you need to include HTML and you're sure it's safe to do so, you can use innerHTML:

```
document.querySelector(".element").innerHTML = "<p class='para'>My text here</p>";
```

If you're  not sure it's safe to do so, you should stick to using one of the [more modern methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51140250/1191147) for adding HTML to the DOM, such as [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) or even [setHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setHTML) with a Sanitiser object if you'll be dealing with a lot of user input.

Answer (score -1):

You can use innerHTML for span elements also.

What happened when you tried to do that?

For a brief example you can look at:
http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/149023-there-faster-way-change-span-innerhtml