# How to write a variable undeath the border

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am fairly new to JS and I am trying to make a simple body mass calculation. It takes users height and weight does a calculation and displays it on the screen. Which I have done. Now my problem is I want to display the result as a text under the "clear the information" button. I want to do this using the DOM.

Any help please!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Assignment 4 Starter File</title>

    <style>
      h1 {text-align: center;}

      #calculator
      {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 0px auto;
        border: 2px solid #000;
        padding: 20px;
      }

      #values
      {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 50px auto;
        pading: 20px;
      }

      ul {margin-top: 5px;}


    </style>

    <script>


        // code to be called when button is clicked goes here
        function calculateResult() {

        // this gets the weight
        var weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
        //this gets the height
            var height = document.getElementById("height").value;
            // this calcualtes thet total with a
            var calculate = (weight / Math.pow(height,2)) * 703;
            //rounds to the 2
            var New = calculate.toFixed(2);
            New = parseInt(New);
            alert(New);
          //  alert(" your weight is" + weight);

    if(calculate <=18){
        ("your BMI IS: " + calculate );
      // alert("your less then 18");

        }




        }

        window.onload = function() {

        // reference the button to be clicked  
        var btnCalculate = document.getElementById("calculate");


        // calls the function when the button is clicked
          btnCalculate.onclick = calculateResult; 

        }
    </script>



    </head>

    <body>

      <header>
        <h1>Body Mass Index (BMI) Calculator</h1>  
      </header>



      <section id="calculator">

        <p>
          To determine if you're at a healthy weight, enter the following information
          and calculate your body mass index (BMI). <span>Enter numbers only please</span>
        </p>  

          <form>

        <label for="weight" >Weight (lbs):</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="weight">
        <br>
        <br>

        <label for="height" >Height (inches):</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="height">
        <br>
        <br>       

        <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Click to Calculate Your BMI"> <br>
        <br>
        <input type="reset" value="Clear the Information"> 
    <p style="color: red">The total is <span id= "total"> </span></p></p>


      </section>


      <section id="values">



        BMI values are as follows:
        <ul>
          <li>Below 18: Underweight</li>
          <li>Between 18 and 24.9 : Normal</li>
          <li>Between 25 and 29.9 : Overweight</li>
          <li>Over 30 : Obese</li>
        </ul>

        </p>

      </section>

    <script type="text/javascript">



        </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535268/js-how-to-dynamically-insert-text-into-a-span

Basically, you use the getElementById() to retrieve the span and assign the result you want displayed into its innerHTML field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve this you would use the the innerHTML property.
This returns or sets the HTML content of an element.

So what I would do is to switch your `alert(New);` to `document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = New;` in your `calculateResult()`function.

This will change the HTML content of the span element whose id == "total", to the value of the variable "New".

So it would look something like this.

```
function calculateResult() {

    // this gets the weight
    var weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
    //this gets the height
    var height = document.getElementById("height").value;
    // this calcualtes thet total with a
    var calculate = (weight / Math.pow(height,2)) * 703;
    //rounds to the 2
    var New = calculate.toFixed(2);
    New = parseInt(New);

    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = New;
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j1an8dh7/13/)

Comment: Thank you! Also one last thing. So I want to say if the number is less then 18 I want to display you (there number) and you are under weight. I tried adding  a If statement using the calculate variable. Is that the right way to go?

Comment: So  if(calculate <=18){
      "your are underweight"  ?My problem is how do I reference the number with the words you are under weight underneath it,

Comment: Im not sure i fully understand what it is you want to do, but take a look at this fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/j1an8dh7/15/

I think this is doing what you're asking for. It should atleast give you an idea on ways to achieve it.

Comment: Thank you! I actually made a variable called text. in the If statement made it equal to "underweight". Then I used document.getElementById('expression').firstChild.nodeValue = bmiText; thank you!