# For loop through Array only shows last value

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

I'm trying to loop through an Array which then uses innerHTML to create a new

element for every entry in the array. Somehow my code is only showing the last value from the array. I've been stuck on this for a few hours and can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
window.onload = function() {

// Read value from storage, or empty array
var names = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('locname') || "[]");
var i = 0;

    n = (names.length);
    for (i = 0; i <= (n-1); i++) {
        var list = names[i];
        var myList = document.getElementById("list");
        myList.innerHTML = "<li class='list-group-item' id='listItem'>"+ list + "</li>" + "<br />";
    }
}
```

I have a UL with the id 'list' in my HTML.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your `for` loop:

```
for (i = 0; i <= (n-1); i++) {
    var list = names[i];
    var myList = document.getElementById("list");
    myList.innerHTML += "<li class='list-group-item' id='listItem'>"+ list + "</li>" + "<br />";
}
```

Use `+=` instead of `=`. Other than that, your code looks fine.

Comment: Note that `+=` on `.innerHTML` [is not optimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515383/why-is-element-innerhtml-bad-code). Prefer `myList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlToAppend)`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to first make a div by create element. there you add your innerHTML and after that you can do the appendchild. That will work perfectly for this type of scenario.

```
function displayCountries(countries) {
const countriesDiv = document.getElementById('countriesDiv');
countries.forEach(country => {
    console.log(country.borders);
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add('countryStyle');
    div.innerHTML = `
    <h1> Name : ${country.name.official} </h1>
    <h2> Capital : ${country.capital} </h2>
    <h3> Borders : ${country.borders} </h3>
    <img src="${country.flags.png}">
    `;
    countriesDiv.appendChild(div);
});
```

}