# Populating a select element with comma-separated values using for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a bunch of comma-separated values stored as strings in a JSON file. My aim is to split these values to populate a select element which is based on Selectize.js. Code (excerpt) looks as follows:

```
var options = {};

var attr_split = data.attributes['Attribute1'].split(",");

var options_key;

for (var i = 0; i < attr_split.length; i++) { 
    options_key = attr_split[i]
    }

var options_values = {
    value: options_key,
    text: options_key,
    }

    if (options_key in options)
        options_values = options[options_key];
    options[options_key] = options_values;

$('#input').selectize({
    options: options,
});
```

Although this seems to work, the output in the select element only shows the last iterations done by the for loop. As per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077828/for-loop-in-javascript-outputs-value-only-from-last-iteration)
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24204825/for-loop-through-array-only-shows-last-value), I've tried

```
for (var i = 0; i < attr_split.length; i++) { 
    var options_key += attr_split[i]
    }
```

but this throws me undefined plus all concatenated strings without the separator as per the following example:

```
undefinedAttr1Attr2Attr3
```

When I simply test the loop using manual input of the array elements everything appears fine:

```
for (var i = 0; i < attr_split.length; i++) { 
    var options_key = attr_split[0] || attr_split[1] || attr_split[2]
    }
```

But this is not the way to go, since the number of elements differs per string.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong here? I have the feeling it's something quite straightforward :)

Comment: can you post `data.attributes['Attribute1']`

Comment: Certainly. This is how it's stored in the JSON: `"Attribute1":"Attr1,Attr2"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you declare 'options_key' ,you are not initializing it.so its value is `undefined` .when you concatenate `options_key += attr_split[i]` .in first iteration `options_key` holds `undefined`.so only you are getting `undefinedAttr1Attr2Attr3`.

so declare and initialize `options_key` like.

```
var options_key="";
```

and in your loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < attr_split.length; i++) 
{ 
     options_key = attr_split[i]
}
```

Everytime  you replace `options_key` with value of `attr_split[i]`.so after the loop it will contain last element value.corrected code is

```
for (var i = 0; i < attr_split.length; i++) 
{ 
    options_key += attr_split[i]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This indeed resolves the `undefined`, however leads to all split strings being concatenated again in the select input. Thus like this: `Attr1Attr2Attr3`. My goal is to have the results of the split strings show up as separate values, thus as Attr1, Attr2 and Attr3. This works when using `options_key = attr_split[i]`, but only shows the last iteration. Any idea on how to populate the select with the separated values, including all other iterations next to also the last one?

Comment: can you post the code that populates `select` element.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle! I think I get how it works in your example. My options are however populated in an `options` variable, which is then fed into an input element which is based on Selectize.js. I added the code which does this to the original post. Any idea on how to do it in this case?

Comment: sry, i am not familiar with selectize.js.Can you give an example structure of options variable.

Comment: Sure, this is what it looks like (JSON):

`{
    "Attr1": {
        "value": "Attr1",
        "text": "Attr1"
    },
    "Attr2": {
        "value": "Attr2",
        "text": "Attr2"
    }
}`

Comment: here is your fiddle-https://jsfiddle.net/balajisoundar/g4Lcq1t7/. i moved `var options_values = {
    value: options_key,
    text: options_key,
    }

    if (options_key in options)
        options_values = options[options_key];
    options[options_key] = options_values;` into your `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

Just change `var options_key;` to `var options_key="";`

The reason you are getting undefined is because you have not defined the variable properly.

Here is a working example

```
 var attr_split = "1,2,3,4".split(",");

var options_key="";

for (var i = 0; i < attr_split.length; i++) { 
    options_key += attr_split[i]
    }

    alert(options_key);
var options_values = {
    value: options_key,
    text: options_key
}
alert(options_values);
```

Comment: Thank you. Please see my comment on the previous answer for a follow-up question.