# JavaScript code blocking CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I insert this code into my file it seems to block my CSS from showing. I made a script to try and print text once the page has loaded which I am then going to use later to make a loaded bar. This is my code. All that happens is I get the text "Test" printed on my page.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css">
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('index').innerHTML = "test";
    }
    </script>
</head>

<!-- Page Body -->
<body id="index" onload="myFunction()">
    <div class="header">
        <div id="headerbar"></div>
        <ul id="">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: With `innerHTML` you are deleting all `div`s inside `index`.

Comment: Currently, I think your code is completely replacing the contents of the body tag with the word "test" (which removes the header). I don't know what your CSS looks like, but it may be that you're just deleting everything in the page, not preventing CSS from showing up.

Comment: Yes you were correct.

Comment: you can use `+=` but this is bad practice apparently, as [it makes it re parse stuff again](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11515395/908879) -disclaimer: that is an answer to one of my questions

Answer (score 4):

When you set the `innerHTML` of the `index` element, it completely replaces everything in the body. So you no longer have the `DIV` with the `header` class, and you no longer have the `DIV` with the `headerbar` ID. There's nothing for your CSS to refer to. It's as if you had written:

```
<body id="index">test</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well for one we have no way of knowing what your CSS does, but an issue I see is that when you are using `innerHTML` it overwrites existing HTML. As in everything inside the `body` tag is overwritten to just test text.

Caveat: My presumption is that you don't have styles on the body either.

Comment: Yes, you were correct. Is there a way to just write html code into the doccument? Once the doccument loads I would like to simply just add another css doccument.

Comment: For 'test' purposes you could change your innerHTML reference to the header bar div. Also you can write HTML code I where you put 'test' etc.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your CSS supposed to style when you set the innerHTML of your body element to "test" ? You're removing all other contained elements by doing this.

I guess what you wanted to do is add a text node like this:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("test"));
```

Comment: Well that prints text, but my goal is to add to the html code. When the page loads I want a bar to pop up. So I did document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='loaded.css'>")); And it just prints it to the screen.

Comment: Yes this is what a "TextNode" does you may want to consider adding some kind of different element using `var l = document.createElement("link"); l.setAttribute("rel","stylesheet"); ...`. Do your homework, use google.