# need time delay when each row has printed on success call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, d3.js

How can I delay each row and while delay interval it shows `processing please wait...`? I tried `setInterval()` but it does not work.

```
url: '/assessment/omr-evaluation/post-omr-skill-based-career-test.aspx',
  data: {
    row: data
  },
  async: false,
  success: function(data) {
    var arr = new Array();
    var names = data
    arr = names.split('^');
    var userTable = $('#user_table_id');
    if (userTable == null || userTable.length == 0) {
      var table_html = "<table id='user_table_id'>";
      table_html += "<tr><td>Name</td><td>Email</td><td>Phone</td><td>PDf</td></tr>";

      table_html += "</table>";
      $('#candy').html(table_html);
    }
    userTable = $('#user_table_id');
    // table_html += "<tr><td>Name</td><td>Email</td><td>Phone</td><td>PDf</td></tr>";
    var newLine = $("<tr><td>" + arr[0] + "</td><td>" + arr[1] + "</td><td>" + arr[2] + "</td><td>" + arr[3] + "</td></tr>");
    userTable.append(newLine);
  },

  error: function(result) {
    alert("Error");
  }
})

 return result;
}
```

Data returned:

```
Gunjan Chaudhary    Gunajndd@....com    8510847200  <a href="http://local.assessment/pdf/1828182.pdf" rel="nofollow">local.assessment/pdf/1828182.pdf</a> Tannu Kuamari Tannukumaridd@....com   8743992787  <a href="http://local.assessment/pdf/1828182.pdf" rel="nofollow">local.assessment/pdf/1828182.pdf</a> Kiran Paswan  Kiranpasddwan@....com   8800134507  <a href="http://local.assessment/pdf/1828182.pdf" rel="nofollow">local.assessment/pdf/1828182.pdf</a>
```

Comment: Can you show us your ajax response ? `SetTimeout` will help!

Comment: Please show more code. Also you cannot return a result from a function that does an async call

Comment: Gunjan Chaudhary Gunajndd@sbpbic.com 8510847200 http://local.assessment/pdf/1828182.pdf
Tannu Kuamari Tannukumaridd@sbpbic.com 8743992787 http://local.assessment/pdf/1828182.pdf
Kiran Paswan Kiranpasddwan@sbpbic.com 8800134507 http://local.assessment/pdf/1828182.pdf

Comment: this is data come as response but need some delay in each row

Comment: @DheerajSharma, Is response in json format ?

Comment: @rayon yeah it was json and now i make this in array to show in html because we make this string in server side

Comment: Will you mind sharing `json` ?

Comment: And when sharing UPDATE THE QUESTION instead of pasting the code in comments

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve something like this:

#### [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

If you want to execute a function continuously with delay.

**Example:**

```
var interval = setInterval(function to be executed..., delay)
```

#### [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

If you want to execute a function after certain delay.

**Example:**

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function to be executed..., delay)
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/et4dofaa/)

#### Code

```js
function createData() {
  var data = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 10;) {
    data.push({
      "index": i,
      "rowNum": ++i,
      "content": "test_" + i
    });
  }
  return data;
}

function appendRow(data, i) {
  var html = document.createElement("tr");
  var tdHtml = "";
  tdHtml += "<td>" + data[i].index + "</td>";
  tdHtml += "<td>" + data[i].rowNum + "</td>";
  tdHtml += "<td>" + data[i].content + "</td>";
  html.innerHTML = tdHtml;

  document.getElementById("content").appendChild(html);
}

function loadTable() {
  var data = createData();
  var index = 0;

  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    appendRow(data, index);
    index++;

    if (index >= data.length)
      window.clearInterval(interval);
  }, 1000);
}

loadTable();
```

```html
<table id="content">
  <tr>
    <th>Index</th>
    <th>Row</th>
    <th>Content</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

#### Edit 1

Updated logic to replace `innerHTML +=` to `appendChild`. Reference [Why is “element.innerHTML+=” bad code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515383/why-is-element-innerhtml-bad-code). Credits @Rayon Dabre

Comment: Looks good! __But__, `innerHTML +=` is terrible. Also explain why `setInterval` is preferred over `SetTimeout `

Comment: `setInterval` will loop automatically. Creating a `timeout` and adding it inside a loop is an over kill, i my understanding. Also my apologies for `innerHTML +=`. Will look for a better solution and will update my answer. Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: @RayonDabre have updated my code and credited. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: innerHTML is not horrible, only here where you already use createElement and appendChild is it silly.