# Drawing to one canvas clears my other canvas elements

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm building a photo upload tool where adding a photo generates a new preview div with an input field to name your photo and a `canvas` element which I draw their picture to so they can preview it. The idea is to allow them to select multiple photos and preview them before uploading them all at once. The problem I have is when you add a second photo, when it draws the image to the newly generated canvas it clears the contents of all the other canvas elements. Here's my code

```
   function createPhotoPreviewDiv(img){
      var canvas_id = "previewCanvas" + $('.previewDivCanvas').length;
      var preview = "<div class='previewDiv'><span>Photo 1</span>" +
                    "<input type='text' placeholder='photo1' class='previewPhotoName'>" +
                    "<canvas class='previewDivCanvas' id='" + canvas_id + "'></canvas>" +
                   "</div>";

      document.getElementById('editLocationPreviewContainer').innerHTML+= preview;

      var canvas = document.getElementById(canvas_id);
      canvas.width = 200;
      canvas.height = 100;
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

   }
```

It works fine, except that when it runs a second time (when the user adds a second photo) then the canvas it had previously created is cleared. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong, or is this expected behavior with multiple canvas elements?

Comment: To add a new element, you should use `.append()` instead of trying to concatenate the inner HTML.

Comment: @darkcrystale Thanks, that actually fixed it. I don't understand why exactly though, as far as I can tell the elements come out the same either way, I was under the impression that both methods were pretty much interchangeable?

Comment: I think it's less clear than `.append()` because with `.append()` you see immediately that you want to *add* something to the element :) See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515383/why-is-element-innerhtml-bad-code But I don't know why it resolved your problem.

Comment: @darkcrystale Thanks for the link! Now that I'm thinking about it, it has become obvious to me - using `innerHTML+=` will redraw the canvases I'd already created, meaning I was replacing the old canvases with fresh ones that hadn't been drawn on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @darckcrystale's comment, I figured out that the issue was caused by me adding the new elements with `innerHTML` instead of `.append()`. By using `innerHTML` I was replacing all the canvas elements I had previously created, which cleared the images I had drawn into them.

Comment: Hey @AnuragDaolagajao, what is it about this answer that's a problem? This is what solved the problem I was having. Can you tell me what I need to do to improve this so its an acceptable answer?