# chrome extension changing element color

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to change all `h1`'s background color to red for example.

At my popup.js that is linked to popup.html I've added this code:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
      {code:"document.getElementsByTagName('h1').style.backgroundColor='red';"});
```

it works fine with `document.body`, but I have no idea how to make it works with `getelementbytagname`

Also I'd like to add some text in the `h1` container.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName('h1')` returns multiple results: an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) to be precise.

You can't set `.style` on the collection itself.

In recent Chrome versions (51+), you can loop through it with `for..of`:

```
let headers = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');
for (let header of headers) {
  header.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

To add text to the `header` node, you can use standard DOM manipulation methods, e.g. [`.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):

```
header.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Boo!"));
```

Or, you could manipulate its `.textContent`.

As your code grows in complexity, you should put it in a dedicated `.js` file and call [`executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) with `file` instead of `code`.

Answer (score 0):

I've added something like this:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    code: "for (var z=0; z < 7; z++) { var el = document.getElementsByTagName('h' + z); for (var i=0; i < el.length; i++) { el[i].style.color ='red'; el[i].innerHTML += '[H' + z + ']';} }" 

});
```

and it's finnaly works :) Now I need to check if var el exists so it won't be marked multipe times.

Comment: Note: `innerHTML` manipulation [considered harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515383/why-is-element-innerhtml-bad-code).

Comment: is there better way to achieve marking h1 tags on website?