# HTML elements in template strings in JS

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I have problem with adding HTML elements in my template string. I want to add new lines in my `<li>` element, but `<br>` is interpreted like string.

```
let movieDescription = document.createTextNode(`${moviesData[i].title} <br> ${moviesData[i].year} <br> ${moviesData[i].genre} <br>${moviesData[i].summary}`);
```

How can I add `<br>` element in template string?

Comment: You create a TextNode, so this is the correct behavior. Use `innerHTML` if you want your string to be parsed.

Comment: why would you expect any different when creating a *"text node"*?

Comment: You should check out [`diffhtml`](https://diffhtml.org/#html). It has some pretty slick functions that do this and tons of other stuff with template tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have already been informed, `<br>` is HTML not text. So you'll need to parse the Template Literal in order to render line breaks correctly. The most common way to do it is by using the property `.innerHTML`, although I've read plenty of [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11515395/2813224) and [blogs](http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2007/12/38/) about how crappy it is, I've never had a problem with it. In this example, we are using `insertAdjacentHTML()` (note the template literal has `<div>`s and `<hr>`s):

```
var movieDescription = `
<hr>
<div>Title: ${moviesData[i].title}</div> 
<div>Year: ${moviesData[i].year}</div> 
<div>Genre: ${moviesData[i].genre}</div> 
<div>Summary: ${moviesData[i].summary}</div>
<hr>`;

 document.querySelector('.dock').innerHTML = movieDescription;
```

---

An alternative method is [**`insertAdjacentHTML()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML). It's like `innerHTML` on steroids.

**Pros:**

- it's faster and safer than `innerHTML`
- it allows us to specifically determine where the insertion should be relating to the target element:

  - `beforebegin`: **inserted HTML** `<div>target element</div>`
  - `afterbegin`: `<div>` **inserted HTML** `target element</div>`
  - `beforeend`: `<div>target element` **inserted HTML** `</div>`
  - `afterend`: `<div>target element</div>` **inserted HTML**
- It doesn't overwrite content like `innerHTML` does.

**Cons:**

- It's verbose.

### Demo

```js
var dock = document.querySelector('.dock');
var i;
var moviesData = [{
  title: 'Pulp Fiction',
  year: '1994',
  genre: 'Drama-Crime',
  summary: "You will know , my name is the Lord, when I lay my vengance upon thee!"
}, {
  title: 'Reservoir Dogs',
  year: '1992',
  genre: 'Drama-Crime',
  summary: "Clowns to the left of me, jokers to the right! Here I am stuck in the middle with you"
}];

for (i = 0; i < moviesData.length; i++) {

  var movieDescription = `
<hr>
<div>Title: ${moviesData[i].title}</div> 
<div>Year: ${moviesData[i].year}</div> 
<div>Genre: ${moviesData[i].genre}</div> 
<div>Summary: ${moviesData[i].summary}</div>
<hr>`;

  dock.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', movieDescription);
}
```

```html
<div class='dock'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A text node contains... well... text. It does not contain other html elements, and thus when you create one it will interpret the `<br>` as text and display it as is.

What you want would be a collection of TextNodes and HTMLBRElement.

```
const movieDescription = [
    document.createTextNode(moviesData[i].title),
    document.createElement('br'),
    document.createTextNode(moviesData[i].year),
    document.createElement('br'),
    document.createTextNode(moviesData[i].genre),
    document.createElement('br'),
    document.createTextNode(moviesData[i].summary)
];
```

That is quite awkward to do. Instead, you probably want to use `Element.innerHTML` on the element you want to add this description to.

```
const html = `${moviesData[i].title} <br> ${moviesData[i].year} <br> ${moviesData[i].genre} <br>${moviesData[i].summary}`;
document.querySelector('.my-movie-description').innerHTML = html;
```

A similar method exists to add a single TextNode to an element. This is `Element.innerText`.

Answer (score 0):

I have witten a html templating engine to render dynamic data at browser.

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/TwilightTitus/full/aEBZRz?editors=1100)

```js
var moviesData = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   moviesData.push( {
      "title" : "title " + i,
      "year" : 2000 + i,
      "genre" : "action",
      "summary" : "summary " + i
   });
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #a3d5d3;
}
.movie {
  margin: 0.5em 1em ;
  padding : 0.2em 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div jstl-autorun jstl-foreach="${moviesData}" jstl-foreach-var="movieData">
   <div class="movie">
      ${movieData.title}
      <br/>
      ${movieData.year}
      <br/>
      ${movieData.genre}
      <br/>
      ${movieData.summary}
   </div>      
</div>
```

[here is the link for the template engine](https://twilighttitus.github.io/jquery.plugins/index.html?module=jstl&page=1)

I hope it's useful for you.