# adding to innerHTML after JavaScript for loop

Tags: javascript, html

So im just testing a basic functionality on JavaScript. Im trying to set the `<li>` within the `<ul>` but for some simple reason my `li` gets placed outside the `ul`.

```js
var test = document.getElementById('testdiv');
var data = [1,2,3,4,5];
    
test.innerHTML += '<ul>'; 
for (var i = 0; i < data[i]; i++)
{
test.innerHTML += '<li>' + i + '=' + data[i] + '</li>';
} 
test.innerHTML += '</ul>';
```

```css
.start{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
  
     <div class="start" id="testdiv"></div>
```

Current `html` outcome looks like this:

```
<div class="start" id="testdiv">
 <ul></ul>
 <li>0=1</li>
 <li>1=2</li>
 <li>2=3</li>
 <li>3=4</li>
 <li>4=5</li>
</div>
```

Expected **outcome** with an simple explanation would be much appreciated.

```
<div class="start" id="testdiv">
  <ul>
   <li>0=1</li>
   <li>1=2</li>
   <li>2=3</li>
   <li>3=4</li>
   <li>4=5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You're writing to the DOM, not to document file. In the DOM, you can create whole elements only, and they are placed to the DOM at once.

Comment: Building html with innerHTML is NOT like building a string. when you just do  

    `test.innerHTML += '<ul>';`

The browser is actually doing this:

    `test.innerHTML += '<ul></ul>';`

so it is closed.

Comment: thanks @epascarello i actually tested it now and realized whats happening thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@MikeChristensen [explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11515395/7914637) why it is bad practice to use `innerHtml` within `for` loop.

> Every time innerHTML is set, the HTML has to be parsed, a DOM constructed, and inserted into the document.

Try to use temporary string variable instead:

```
var myList = '<ul>';
for (var i = 0; i < data[i]; i++) { 
  myList += '<li>' + i + '=' + data[i] + '</li>'; 
} 
myList += '</ul>';
test.innerHTML = myList;
```

Comment: @Ylama , I saw additional question from you. But I don't see the message now. Do you still have a question or you solve it yourself?

Comment: Yess @Alexander please help me understand, why if `myList` is part of the loop only gets added once? your anwser is exactly 100% correct what i want it just confuses me that the 'li' gets populated 5times and the `ul` once but they are in the same loop, hope it makes sense what im asking?

Comment: `var myList = '<ul>'` sets initial accumulator value. Then the `myList` is concatenated with `<li>...</li>` for each element of the `data` array (see `+=` [assignment operator](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_assignment.asp)). Finally, we append close `</ul> tag and insert accumulated string into HTML block. My code is same as your, but I build string at first, and then write it to HTML.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander now i understand much better!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using above approach you can use below one.

> Possible reason is browser might adding the closing tag automatically to the opened tag.

```js
var test = document.getElementById('testdiv');
var data = [1,2,3,4,5];
var ulelement = document.createElement("ul");    
for (var i = 0; i < data[i]; i++)
{
ulelement.innerHTML += '<li>' + i + '=' + data[i] + '</li>';
} 
test.appendChild(ulelement);
```

```css
.start{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="start" id="testdiv"></div>
```

Comment: nice interesting approach , thanks for the help, so the browser ads closing tags automatically?

Comment: actually tested it and it does add the closing `tag` automatically.. so my approach is wrong but i actually got this out a book and could not understand why its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use `appendChild()` method instead:

```js
var test = document.getElementById('testdiv');
var ul = document.createElement('UL');

var data = [1,2,3,4,5];
    
for (var i = 0; i < data[i]; i++)
{
  var li = document.createElement('LI');
  li.innerHTML = i + '=' + data[i];
  ul.appendChild(li);
} 

test.appendChild(ul)
```

```css
.start{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="start" id="testdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with li last element was not getting populated in my case.

I changed my code
**From**

```
$('.ul_food_item').innerHTML = li_elem_new;
```

**To**

```
$('.ul_food_item').html(li_elem_new);
```

My problem was solved.