# adding dynamically the data into the columns of the table in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function add_fields() {
  document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML += '<tr> <td> <textarea name = "Product ID" placeholder = "Product ID"  style = "resize: none; width: 100%;"    document.getElementById("1")></textarea></td> <td> <textarea name = "Title" placeholder = "Title"   style = "resize: none; width: 100%;"></textarea></td><td> <textarea name = "startdate" placeholder = "startdate"   style = "resize: none; width: 100%;"></textarea></td> </tr>';
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="set-form">
  <input type="button" id="more_fields" onclick="add_fields();" value="Add More" class="btn btn-info" />
</div>


<table id="myTable">
  product id : <input type="text" name="fname" id="1"><br>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product ID</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Start Date</th>
      <th>End Date</th>
      <th>Excl</th>
      <th>Territory</th>
      <th>Media</th>
      <th>Language</th>
      <th>Format</th>
      <th>Acquiring Division</th>
      <th>Owner</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

I want to add dynamically to the table by selecting the id whenever the user enters the data the data should add automatically to the table.

Is there any better way I want to add a column to the table and data to be added at once but I could not figure out so I planned the above code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: besides of your main question, did you forget passing ID to the function so the created row contains that id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing a little with your code, I made the following modifications…

- HTML stays in HTML, I've added a `tr` with `id="row-type"`. It's hidden but the content is used to add a new `tr` when you click <kbd>Add More</kbd>. I've modified your existing function accordingly.
- CSS stays in CSS, I've moved the `table textarea` style in the CSS.
- As it's not recommended to use `.innerHTML +=`, I replaced it with `.appendChild(…)`.
- I've added a `button` in the `row-type` element. So that, when you click <kbd>Submit</kbd>, the content of the row is converted from textareas to texts.
- As we're only adding in the 3 first `td`s, I've removed some of the other `td`s in the HTML to shorten the snippet. But it works exactly the same with all of it (I tried).
- I've added a cancel function, in case you finally don't want to add.

…and ended-up with this working snippet:
(See comments in the code for more details)

```js
// TAKIT: Now the content is in the HTML, append it to the current table
function add_fields() {
  // TAKIT: Replaced .innerHTML as it's not recommended
  var newElement = document.createElement('tr');
  newElement.innerHTML = document.getElementById('row-type').innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('myTable').appendChild(newElement);
}

// TAKIT: Added this function for when you click on the submit button
function put_in_table(elm) {
  var tds = elm.closest('tr').children; // Get all tds of the line you just clicked "submit"
  for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) { // For all tds
    // replace the HTML with the text value of the textarea (that removes the textareas)
    if (tds[i].innerHTML)
      tds[i].innerText = tds[i].children[0].value || '';
  }
}

// TAKIT: Added this function to cancel the add
function cancel_add(elm) {
  elm.closest('tr').outerHTML = ''; // Empty current tr
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}


/* TAKIT: Added hidden on row type, and moved style of textareas here */

#row-type {
  display: none;
}

table textarea {
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="set-form"><input type="button" id="more_fields" onclick="add_fields();" value="Add More" class="btn btn-info" /></div>
<table id="myTable">
  <!-- TAKIT: Added p element here, it's proper. What is it used for, by the way? -->
  <p>product id : <input type="text" name="fname" id="1"></p>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product ID</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Start Date</th>
      <th>End Date</th>
      <th>Excl</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- TAKIT: Added body and the "row-type" in it, so that HTML stays in HTML -->
    <tr id="row-type">
      <td><textarea name="Product ID" placeholder="Product ID"></textarea></td>
      <td><textarea name="Title" placeholder="Title"></textarea></td>
      <td><input name="startdate" type="date"></td>
      <td><input name="enddat" type="date"></td>
      <td>
        <button onclick="put_in_table(this);">Submit</button> <button onclick="cancel_add(this);">Cancel</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks a lot
 but how to place date field instead of text area

Comment: @m.dvenkateshm You only need to make changes in the "row-type". I've updated and added `input`s with `type="date"`.

Answer (score 0):

I find it easiest to just have a div/span which I write a table in dynamically with javascript, e.g.

```js
example_array = [["Name","Age"],["Antonio","35"]];

function array_to_table(my_array){
  my_table_html = '<table>';
  for(var i = 0; i<my_array.length; i++){
    my_table_html += "<tr>";
    for(var j = 0; j < my_array[i].length; j++){
      my_table_html += "<td>"+my_array[i][j]+"</td>";
    }
    my_table_html += "</tr>";
  }
  my_table_html += '</table>';
  document.getElementById("mytable").innerHTML = my_table_html;
}

array_to_table(example_array);
```

```html
<div id="mytable"></div>
```

When you have this framework for creating/updating tables, you can edit the array that's fed into the function to dynamically update your table.

Comment: It isn't recommended to use `innerHTML += `, read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515383/why-is-element-innerhtml-bad-code) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example, enter the desired values in the first row (I have only the first three elements here). Then click <kbd>Add</kbd>, the row will be added to the table.

```js
function add_fields() {

  // select the input values
  let productId = document.querySelector('#productId').value
  let title = document.querySelector('#title').value
  let startDate = document.querySelector('#startDate').value

  // prepare a new row
  let tr = document.createElement('tr')
  tr.innerHTML = `
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="productId" style="resize: none; width: 100%;">${productId}</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="title" style="resize: none; width: 100%;">${title}</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="startDate" style="resize: none; width: 100%;">${startDate}</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  `
  
  // remove content of textareas
  document.querySelector('#productId').value = ''
  document.querySelector('#title').value = ''
  document.querySelector('#startDate').value = ''
  
  // append a new row to the table
  document.querySelector('#myTable').appendChild(tr)

}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="set-form">
  <input type="button" id="more_fields" onclick="add_fields();" value="Add" class="btn btn-info" />
</div>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Product ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>End Date</th>
        <th>Excl</th>
        <th>Territory</th>
        <th>Media</th>
        <th>Language</th>
        <th>Format</th>
        <th>Acquiring Division</th>
        <th>Owner</th>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <textarea id="productId" placeholder="Product ID" style="resize: none; width: 100%;"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
          <textarea id="title" placeholder="Title" style="resize: none; width: 100%;"></textarea></td>
        <td>
          <textarea id="startDate" placeholder="startdate" style="resize: none; width: 100%;"></textarea> </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
```

Here are a couple things you might want to know:

- I'm using the method `querySelector()` from `document` to select an element from the DOM by its class or id. Don't forget to add the `#` to `.` before the actual name.
- Access the value of an element of type `textarea` with its property `value`.
- No use of `innerHTML +=` as it will force the browser to re-render all the content of `#myTable` even if you're just adding a row. Best way is to prepare an element as I do and append it to the table with `appendChild()`.
- To easily write HTML inside JavaScript code, you can use backticks `` and insert JS variables directly in the markup with the `${}` syntax.