# How do I convert an internal <script> tag to an external Javascript file? (for random image generator)

Tags: javascript, html, random, type-conversion, generator

I'm trying to convert an internal HTML script element into an external Javascript file. The `<script>` element works perfectly in HTML, but I don't understand what I need to change in order for it to work from an external Javascript file. What I have right now "fires" - it does generate the random images - but it shows them full screen, blocking off the entire website.

Here is the working HTML `<script>`

```
 <script class="randomad" type="text/javascript">
            var total_images = 7;
            var random_number = Math.floor((Math.random()*total_images));
            var random_img = new Array();
            random_img[0] = '<a href="http://www.antares-sellier.com/en/"><img src="javascript/js_images/antares.jpg"></a>';
            random_img[1] //....1-5 excluded here for brevity//
            random_img[6] = '<a href="http://www.scesports.org/"><img src="javascript/js_images/sces.jpg"></a>';
            document.write(random_img[random_number]);
            </script>
```

In the HTML file, I've replaced the script element with:

```
           <div id="firstads"></div>
```

and added

```
<script src="javascript/rec_images.js" async></script>
```

to the head element.

In Javascript, I've removed the script tags and added a function, but I'm pretty new to Javascript and can't figure out what else I need to add or change to make the conversion work properly

Here is the malfunctioning Javascript code:

```
window.onload = random_ad;

 function random_ad () {
     document.getElementById("firstads");
    var total_images = 7;
    var random_number = Math.floor((Math.random()*total_images));
    var random_img = new Array();
    random_img[0] = '<a href="http://www.antares-sellier.com/en/"><img src="javascript/js_images/antares.jpg"></a>';
//....1-5 excluded here for brevity//
    random_img[6] = '<a href="http://www.scesports.org/"><img src="javascript/js_images/sces.jpg"></a>';
    document.write(random_img[random_number]);

 }
```

The goal is to have a hyperlinked image randomly generated in by an external JavaScript file. The images need to be small enough to fit in an aside column, but right now they are the size of the browser. I'd really appreciate any help with fixing this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot right, but you are missing a few little things.

There are also a number of different ways you can complete this task. The following is as close as possible to your original code.

In the HTML `<head>` element, a very minor change.

```
<script defer src="javascript/rec_images.js"></script>
```

Why `defer` over `async`? Well, [that will depend on what you are doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808109/script-tag-async-defer), but in most cases and based on the small code sample, I believe that would be the best match.

In `javascript/rec_images.js`, a few changes.

```
/*
    Pass the div id to the function to add the image.
*/
function random_ad(divId) {
    var random_img = [
        {link:"http://www.antares-sellier.com/en/",
           image:"javascript/js_images/antares.jpg"},
        // add as many as you want
        {link:"http://www.scesports.org/",
           image:"javascript/js_images/sces.jpg"}
       ];
    var random_number = Math.floor((Math.random()*random_img.length));
    var d = document.getElementById(divId);
    // always best to check the element was found.
    if (d) {
       var a = document.createElement("a");
       var i = document.createElement("img");
       a.setAttribute("href",random_img[random_number].link);
       i.setAttribute("src",random_img[random_number].image);
       a.appendChild(i);
       d.appendChild(a);
    }
 }
```

Back in the `HTML`, where you have `<div id="firstads"></div>`, right at the bottom, before the closing `</body></html>`, add this:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    // pass the div id to the function
    random_ad("firstads");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**

Change to using `createElement`, [which is encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515383/why-is-element-innerhtml-bad-code) for sure. Was being lazy using `innerHTML` before.

Comment: This makes sense, and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Tigger.

You are using document.write() here:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp

'The write() method writes HTML expressions or JavaScript code to a document.'
'The write() method is mostly used for testing: If it is used after an HTML document is fully loaded, it will delete all existing HTML.'

document.write() can be useful sometimes, but is generally not standard practice.
You need to set innerHTML or append a HTML DOM element instead. You can add it to the end of the body like this:

```
// ... random_img setups
// replacing document.write
document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += (random_img[random_number]);
```

You can use querySelector, getElementById, getElementsByClassName and other selectors. I recommend querySelector in general, google for examples :).

Also, if you have time over I would recommend that you check out document.createElement, and append function to add elements to a tag, instead of setting innerHTML by text. Here is some answers to why innerHTML is discouraged:
[Why is "element.innerHTML+=" bad code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515383/why-is-element-innerhtml-bad-code)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'll definitely keep that in mind!