# Issues while dynamically appending content including inline javascript and style

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html markup for a list

```
<ul>
    <a id="catalogPlaceholder"></a> <!-- this is the placeholder to append new items -->

    <a class="sidebarListItem" href="#link">        
        <object type="deleteLinkOnHover"><a class="deleteItem" href="javascript:deleteItemFromList()">Delete</a></object>
        <div style="width:30%;float:left; background: none"><img class="rounded-circle" src="#image" alt="Product image" width="100%"></div>
        <div style="float:left;padding-left:10px;width:60%;background: none"><strong class="text-muted d-block mb-2"><h5>#title</h5></strong></div>        
    </a>
    <a class="sidebarListItem" href="#link">        
        <object type="deleteLinkOnHover"><a class="deleteItem" href="javascript:deleteItemFromList()">Delete</a></object>
        <div style="width:30%;float:left; background: none"><img class="rounded-circle" src="#image" alt="Product image" width="100%"></div>
        <div style="float:left;padding-left:10px;width:60%;background: none"><strong class="text-muted d-block mb-2"><h5>#title</h5></strong></div>        
    </a>
    <a class="sidebarListItem" href="#link">        
        <object type="deleteLinkOnHover"><a class="deleteItem" href="javascript:deleteItemFromList()">Delete</a></object>
        <div style="width:30%;float:left; background: none"><img class="rounded-circle" src="#image" alt="Product image" width="100%"></div>
        <div style="float:left;padding-left:10px;width:60%;background: none"><strong class="text-muted d-block mb-2"><h5>#title</h5></strong></div>        
    </a>
</ul>
```

that looks like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljmrt.gif)

and want to add new items using javascript like this

```
function relateNewCatalog(id, image, title) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.classname = "sidebarListItem";
    a.id = "sidebarItemCatalog-" + id;
    a.href = "../?module=catalogDetails&idcatalog=" + id;
    a.style = "padding:10px";
        
    var html = '<object type="deleteLinkOnHover"><a class="deleteItem" href="javascript:deleteItemFromList(\'sidebarItemCatalog-' + id +  '\')">Delete</a></object>';
    html += '<div style="width:30%;float:left; background: none"><img class="rounded-circle" src="../uploads/images/' + image + '" alt="Product image" width="100%"></div>';
    html += '<div style="float:left;padding-left:10px;width:60%;background: none"><strong class="text-muted d-block mb-2"><h5>' + title + '</h5></strong></div>';        

    a.innerHTML = html;
    var placeholder = document.getElementById("catalogPlaceholder");
    placeholder.append(a);
}
```

but the markup seems broken when I do so like in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoaR7.gif) (see padding and hover effect). I tried `clear:both` and also with `insertBefore` instead of `appendChild` but without success. The more items I add the more they get stacked like in the [last image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBdlo.gif)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You are appending items to the first `a` tag. But you should add them to the `ul` tag. `id=catalogPlaceholder`  should go for `ul`.

Comment: Great, the markup is correct now, but the hover effect still doesnt work. Any ideas for that?

Comment: See if `before()` or `after()` work for you. Look at exact description of functions in [jquery Api](https://api.jquery.com/) so you can find the best choice.

Comment: *"...but the markup seems broken..."* `<ul>` and  `<ol>` must have  `<li>` as the only direct descendants (te children). Any other element (like `<a>`) is invalid HTML. Not only is formatting screwed up but so is DOM traversal by JavaScript/jQuery. Change that `<ul>` to a `<nav>` and you won't get unexpected results.

Comment: I know, unsolicited edits can be annoying, but I think you are not quite right with your grammar rules concerning the correct use of "an" in English, see here: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/155

Comment: HTML *does* start with a vowel sound: "H" as a spelled out letter sounds like /eɪtʃ/ ("aitch").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<template>` and separate data and view as follows

```js
let data = [
  { id: 1, title: 'Product 1', image: "https://picsum.photos/id/10/50" },
  { id: 2, title: 'Product 2', image: "https://picsum.photos/id/20/50" },
  { id: 3, title: 'Product 3', image: "https://picsum.photos/id/30/50" }
]

function refresh() {
  let r='', inj = (str, obj) => str.replace(/\${(.*?)}/g, (x,g)=> obj[g]);
  for(let it of data) r += inj(item.innerHTML,it);
  catalogPlaceholder.innerHTML = r;
}

function relateNewCatalog() {
  data.unshift({
    id: Math.max(...data.map(x=>x.id),0)+1, 
    title: `Product ${data.length+1}`, 
    image: `https://picsum.photos/id/${Math.random()*300|0}/50` 
  });
  refresh();
}

function deleteItemFromList(id) {
  data = data.filter(x=> x.id!=id);
  refresh();
}

refresh();
```

```css
.sidebarListItem {display: flex}
h5 {margin:0}
```

```html
<button onclick="relateNewCatalog()">Add</button>
<ul id="catalogPlaceholder" ></ul>

<template id="item" >
  <li>
    <a class="sidebarListItem" href="#link">        
      <object type="deleteLinkOnHover">
        <a class="deleteItem" onclick="deleteItemFromList(${id})">Delete</a>
      </object>
      <div class="imgBox">
        <img class="rounded-circle" src="${image}" alt="Product image" >
      </div>
      <div class="titleBox"><strong class="text-muted d-block mb-2">
        <h5>${title}</h5>
      </strong></div>        
    </a>
  </li>
</template>
```

Comment: Nicely presented! Although, you are rebuilding the whole page every time you add another catalogue. This could slow down the page or cause some flickering when there is a large number of catalogues to list. So, maybe `.appendChild()` might come in as a useful alternative to `innerHTML`? (@MBrain: there is no "an" before "useful" ;-) )

Comment: @cars10m you are right - the solution can be improved to not change old products in html tree. By the way in past I made some tests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55970947/860099) and it looks lie `innerHTML =` (do not  confuse with `+=` !) is faster than `.appendChild()` -

Comment: Sorry @MBrain, my wife (English native speaker and professional translator) is looking over my shoulder and is slowly losing the will to live ... The use of "a" or "an" depends solely on the pronunciation of the immediately following word. The word "alternative" is of no relevance here.

Comment: Hi @Kamil, interesting fact about your speed comparison. Will remember that for future projects. You got my +1 already this morning. I hope MBrain is not too cross about my comments and will accept your answer. ;-)