# JavaScript is crashing at adding <br>

Tags: javascript, html

since many days, I'm stuck with if I want to add `<br>` with `elem.innerHTML += '<br>'` or `document.createElement('br')`, the whole site crashes.
But if I am doing this with a normal letter, it works just fine.

```js
  function setSpace(elem){
    if((elem.clientHeight-49)/16 >= 1){
      for(var i=0; i <= (elem.clientHeight-49)/16; i++){
        elem.innerHTML += '<br>';
      }
    }
  }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you code seems to work fine. can you post your html and how are you calling this function?

Comment: *"the whole site crashes"*: what does that mean? Does your loop not finish? Errors in the console? What is a "normal letter"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why-is-element-innerhtml-bad-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515383/why-is-element-innerhtml-bad-code).

Comment: I meant that the site is loading endlessly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop risks to never finish, because you extend the height of the element in every iteration, which is also influencing the stop-condition of the loop. `elem.clientHeight` increases, and `i` might never get greater than `(elem.clientHeight-49)/16`.

A way out is to first get the limit into a variable, and then use that:

```
 function setSpace(elem){
    let end = (elem.clientHeight-49)/16;
    if (end >= 1){
      for(var i=0; i <= end; i++) {
        elem.innerHTML += '<br>';
      }
    }
  }
```

... but stil be careful, as the next time you call `setSpace` it will add even more line breaks. If you keep calling this function, you'll never stop adding line breaks.

Review what your purpose really is with this code.

There are better ways to add spacing to an element, for instance with CSS `padding-bottom`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked.

I am currently working on a chat application and because of position:absolute of the messages, I have to iterate through every message and look, whether it has more than one line and set relative to that the <br>'s to the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's just same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515383/why-is-element-innerhtml-bad-code).

> Every time innerHTML is set, the HTML has to be parsed, a DOM constructed, and inserted into the document. This takes time.

That's causing your browser crashes. Actually not crashes, but it's still processing.

The solution is, you need to use appendChild.

```
function setSpace(elem) {
    var space = document.createElement('div');
    var count = (elem.clientHeight-49)/16;

    if (count >= 1) {
        for (var i=0; i <= count; i++) {
            elem.appendChild(space);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Your code seems to work fine and doesnt crash.
2. If you are trying to increase the height by adding extra 
    that would not be the right approach.

   3. Rather suggest to change the height directly by changing the style properties

Comment: The OP says it "crashes". It does not help them to say it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

You can try: `elem.innerHTML += '\n'`

Comment: This does not add a visible line break to the document.