# Turn long JSON file into single objects

Tags: javascript, json, api

I'm working with a JSON file in Javascript that I want to turn into single objects, where my next step is to have them in different cards in the HTML file.

API JSON file: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos

I have fetched the API:

```
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (json) {
    consoleLogJson(json);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Then I have looped through the results of the JSON:

```
function consoleLogJson(json) {

const resultsContainer = document.querySelector(".results");
const results = json;

    for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        console.log("<div>Title: " + results[i].title + "</div>" + "<div>UserId: " + results[i].userId + "</div>" + "<div>Id: " + results[i].id + "</div>" + "<div>Completed: " + results[i].completed + "</div>");
    }
}
```

This is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>JavaScript - MA04 - Question 2</title>
<body>

<!-- Create a list of TODO cards using the API -->
<div class="results">


</div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am unsure what my next step should be.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much there, just change your `console.log` to instead append HTML to the results container. I would also recommend wrapping the html in a div (your to-do card). So change this part:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    console.log("<div>Title: " + results[i].title + "</div>" + "<div>UserId: " + results[i].userId + "</div>" + "<div>Id: " + results[i].id + "</div>" + "<div>Completed: " + results[i].completed + "</div>");
}
```

To this:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    resultsContainer.innerHTML += ("<div class='todo-card'><div>Title: " + results[i].title + "</div>" + "<div>UserId: " + results[i].userId + "</div>" + "<div>Id: " + results[i].id + "</div>" + "<div>Completed: " + results[i].completed + "</div></div>");
}
```

Comment: But how would I get the objects in the JSON file, in different cards? Thank u :)

Comment: What is a card? The example I provided places the results in divs and attaches a class called 'todo-card' and renders it to the DOM. Can you please be a little more specific of exactly what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

**Add HTML dynamically via `parent.appendChild(child)` and/or `parent.innerHTML = htmlString`.** This is often done via plain strings or using a clone from [template elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template). To keep things simple, I'll show how to do things the "plain string" way. The rest of the work is likely to be in your [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSS) (I've included some example CSS that displays HTML content as cards).

Tips:

- It may take a little extra learning up front, but your life is made a little easier with newer syntax such as [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), [template literal strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), and [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter)
- Using array methods (like [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) below) can help avoid or contain [side-effects](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/40314/169067), making logic easier to follow and/or maintain
- [Do not use `element.innerHTML += str`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515383/why-is-element-innerhtml-bad-code), this could cause the HTML in `str` to be re-parsed on every loop - making it MAJORLY inefficient. Instead, gather all the HTML into a single string and set it once.

```js
;(async () => {
  // Reusable function to fetch JSON resources (and error when not ok)
  const fetchJson = (...args) => fetch(...args).then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error('Network response was not ok.')
    return response.json()
  })

  // Try to fetch data using the above function
  try {
    const todoArray = await fetchJson('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
    
    // Map each todo item to some corresponding HTML
    const todosHTMLArray = todoArray.map(({ title, userId, id, completed }) => `
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card__detail">Title: ${title}</div>
        <div class="card__detail">UserId: ${userId}</div>
        <div class="card__detail">Id: ${id}</div>
        <div class="card__detail">Completed: ${completed}</div>
      </div>
    `)
    
    // Add all the new content from the HTML array above into the js-todos div
    document.querySelector('.js-todos').innerHTML = todosHTMLArray.join('')
  
  // Handle any errors
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
})()
```

```css
:root {
  /* Sizes */
  --size-1: .5rem;
  --size-2: calc(var(--size-1) * 2);
  --size-3: calc(var(--size-1) + var(--size-2));
  --size-4: calc(var(--size-2) + var(--size-3));
  
  /* Colors */
  --color-main-major: #ffffff;
  --color-main-minor: #fafafa;
  --color-main-contrast-major: #222;
  --color-main-contrast-minor: #cccccc;

  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--color-main-minor);
}

.card-list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  gap: var(--size-2);
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1024px;
}

.card {
  display: grid;
  gap: var(--size-1);
  padding: var(--size-3);
  border: 1px solid var(--color-main-contrast-minor);
  background-color: var(--color-main-major);
  box-shadow: var(--size-1) var(--size-1) var(--size-1) var(--color-main-contrast-minor);
}

.card__detail + .card__detail {
  border-top: 1px solid var(--color-main-contrast-minor);
  padding-top: var(--size-2);
}
```

```html
<div class="js-todos card-list"></div>
```