# Insert HTML to a div in a tampermonkey script

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey

How do I insert HTML to a div in a tampermonkey script? I've tried

```js
var htmlll= `
<button>hi</button>
`
document.getElementsByClassName("clasname").innerHTML += htmlll;
```

Although it keeps saying `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null`.

I have tried

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
var htmlll= `
<button>hi</button>
`
document.getElementsByClassName("clasname").innerHTML += htmlll;

});
```

to counter this error,  but it didn't work. It didn't give me an error and it didn't append the html.

Note: I am using vanilla javascript. Please dont answer with jquery solutions.

Comment: What is `jspath`? show the html

Comment: How do you expect us to help if you don't show us the HTML?

Comment: you dont need the html

Comment: the html is just a div with a class name and im trying to append to that

Answer (score 0):

It should be `document.querySelector('.jspath') or '#jspath'`  where you mistakenly wrote only `jspath`

Comment: How do you know? OP hasn't provided the HTML.

Comment: There isn't any html tag named jspath. Is there any tag named that?

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be something like

```
document.getElementsByClassName("clasname")[0].innerHTML += htmlll;
```

since `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection, not a single element.

Comment: I tried this and it still says ``Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null``

Comment: I'm that case there evidently was no element with `class="clasname"` in the document. Maybe it should be "class name"?

Comment: No, the class name is literally clasname

Comment: Don't use `.innerHTML +=`! See [Why is "element.innerHTML+=" bad code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11515383).

Comment: This is a tampermonkey script ... so no need for "page optimisation talk" here ;-)