# javascript foreach with DOM

Tags: javascript, foreach

i'm very new to JS so be nice haha, but i'm trying to create a table of contents on a page using the DOM.

```js
const h2 = document.querySelectorAll('h2');
const toc = document.querySelector('#toc')

h2.forEach(heading => {
    toc.innerHTML = `<li><a href="">${heading}</a></li>`
})
```

it's not working how i would expect tbh. any help is appreaciated, i'm probably just being dumb

Comment: "it's not working how i would expect tbh" — Tell us what it **is** doing, not just what it isn't. Tell us what you expect, don't make us guess.

Comment: ah sorry, i expect it to go through the h2's, print them each out as an <li> on the DOM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think something like this should work! Here's what I changed to get it to work:

- Use `+=` instead of `=` for innerHTML. If you just use `=`, every time the `forEach` runs, it replaces the content. You're trying to create a list, so you want it to add on.
- Get the `innerText` from `heading`. `heading` is an element, so you have to go into it and get its text, or else what you display isn't going to look right.

```js
const h2 = document.querySelectorAll('h2');
const toc = document.querySelector('#toc')

h2.forEach(heading => {
  toc.innerHTML += `<li><a href="">${heading.innerText}</a></li>`
})
```

```html
<ul id="toc"></ul>

<h2>One</h2>
<h2>Two</h2>
```

Comment: A word of caution: innerHTML is usually a bad practice and also not good for performance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515383/why-is-element-innerhtml-bad-code

Answer (score 1):

Regarding @Utkarsh Dixit comment: This is much more performant and is creating the same result.

```js
const h2 = document.querySelectorAll('h2');
const toc = document.querySelector('#toc')

h2.forEach(heading => {
  // Create two elements
  const li = document.createElement('li')
  const anchor = document.createElement('a')

  // Assign the text content to the anchor
  anchor.textContent = heading.textContent

  // Add them together toc > li > anchor
  li.append(anchor)
  toc.append(li)
})
```

```html
<ul id="toc"></ul>

<h2>One</h2>
<h2>Two</h2>
```