# print the arrays in the main window in JavaScript and add css code to it inside the java script

Tags: javascript, html

How can I print the all elements from the array to my main window in the browser and how can i add css code inside the java script?

```js
const arr=["example1" , " example2 " , "example3"]

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

console.log(arr[i]);
 

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by main window ?

Comment: Do you mean `document.body.innerText += arr[i];`?

Comment: If you want to show it in document, then add `document.write(arr.join())`

Comment: thanks alot guys but i have another equestion how can i add the css code for the elements in for loop

Comment: That's a new question. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Check the code, and if you want a different class for each element you can use: `element.innerHTML += '<p class="style'+i+'">'+arr[i]+'</p>';`

```js
const arr=["example1" , " example2 " , "example3"]
const element = document.getElementById("data");

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
element.innerHTML += '<p class="style">'+arr[i]+'</p>' ;

}
```

```css
.style {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="data">
  
</div>
```

Comment: `+=` on `.innerHTML` is discouraged: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515383/why-is-element-innerhtml-bad-code

Comment: thanks alot sir then how can i add css code to every element in the for loop

Comment: @muathsalem let me change the code

Comment: @muathsalem code updated check it :)

Comment: thanks alot sir it was so helpfull for me