# How can I show the output in console.log?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, console.log

I am trying to fetch data from an api into console and then display it on a page.

I have correctly fetched the data from the placeholder api into console.log, but I cannot display it onto the page in the div. What am I doing wrong?

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))

document.getElementById("console")
```

```html
<div id="console"></div>
```

Comment: console.log is for logging in DevTools. It is not a div.

Comment: Thank you. So how can I take the information I have fetched from the API, and display it in page?

Comment: There seems to be some code parts missing. Do you try to add it into the .console div as well? Should be something like `document.getElementById("console").innerHTML = json` ?

Comment: @IngoSteinke Should probably be `innerText` - we wouldn't want to accidentally introduce an opportunity for XSS

Comment: Do you just want to display the object, or do you want to put the data in that object in a table, for example? "display it onto the page in the div" is a little ambiguous.

Comment: My end goal is to display in a table as you have suggested. @Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to output the data as a formatted string you could create a function to "pretty print" the stringified data using `<pre>` and `<code>`.

```js
const output = document.querySelector('.output');

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(updateHTML);

function updateHTML(data) {
  const json = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
  const html = `<pre><code>${json}</code></pre>`;
  output.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
}
```

```html
<div class="output"></div>
```

If you wanted to display the data differently (in a table, for example) you could iterate ([`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) over the keys and values returned by [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/entries) to return a string of row HTML, and add that html to the page.

```js
const output = document.querySelector('.output');

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(updateHTML);

function updateHTML(data) {

  // Get the object entries - and array of key/value pairs
  const entries = Object.entries(data);

  // Iterate over the entries and return a new array
  // of strings created from the key/value using a
  // template string.
  const rows = entries.map(([key, value]) => {
    return `
      <tr>
        <td class="heading">${key}</td>
        <td>${value}</td>
      </tr>
    `;
  });

  // Create a new HTML string by `join`ing up the row array
  // and adding it to a new string
  const html = `<table><tbody>${rows.join('')}</tbody></table>`;

  // Insert the HTML into the page
  output.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
}
```

```css
table { background-color: #efefef; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #afafaf; }
td { padding: 0.4em; border: 1px solid white; }
.heading { text-transform: uppercase; text-align: right; font-weight: 500; background-color: #dfdfdf; }
```

```html
<div class="output"></div>
```

Addition documentation

- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Answer (score 4):

innerHTML could achieve.

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
  console.log(json);
  document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(json)}
  )
```

Comment: `innerText` may be more appropriate for JSON just in case the JSON contains HTML snippets. Don't want to be adding inadvertant `<script>` tags

Comment: `+=` on `.innerHTML` [is discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515383/why-is-element-innerhtml-bad-code).

Comment: I know the OP has it in their question but `.then(json` should probably be `.then(data` as at that point it's no longer JSON as the JSON has been parsed. Edit: just realised that code is in the examples for jsonplaceholder.typicode.com which isn't great, it's just misleading.