# Append text of different style

Tags: javascript, html

Hi is there a way to make the appended "YAY" be of a different style from the "I am happy" text? eg. bigger font-size/ bolded.

```js
document.getElementById("appendButton").onclick = function() {

  document.getElementById("happy").innerHTML += " YAY";

}
```

```html
<p id="happy">I am happy</p>
<button id="appendButton">Click here to cheer!</button>
```

I've tried to give it an id with span, but then the button won't append anything. Would appreciate any help thanks!

Comment: Just create an empty span inside the happy id: `<p id="happy">I am happy<span id="cheer"></span><p>` and then target "cheer" in your onclick instead of "happy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use an id because ids must be unique (which means you can't have more than one on a page and expect the correct output).

Add a class instead.

Note 1: I've used the more modern [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method here.

Note 2: It's also worth mentioning that concatenating HTML strings to `innerHTML` [is considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515383/why-is-element-innerhtml-bad-code). [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) is the better alternative.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('appendButton');
const happy = document.getElementById('happy');

button.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick() {
  happy.innerHTML += '<span class="yay"> YAY</span>';
}
```

```css
.yay { color: blue; font-weight: 600; }
```

```html
<p id="happy">I am happy</p>
<button id="appendButton">Click here to cheer!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can append a `span` element with a class, then style it with CSS:

```js
document.getElementById("appendButton").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("happy").innerHTML += "<span class='large'>YAY</span>";
}
```

```css
.large{
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<p id="happy">I am happy</p>
<button id="appendButton">Click here to cheer!</button>
```