# I cannot find even and odd numbers in an array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know how to find an even or odd number but I can't seem to find any results for finding odd and even numbers in an array. I want to write even numbers in a paragraph in HTML and odd numbers in another paragraph.

```js
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

let e;
let no = numbers.forEach(sort());

function sort() {
  if(numbers[e] % 2 === 0) {
    console.log(`${numbers[e]} is even`);
    // document.querySelector("#even").innerHTML = numbers[e];
  } else {
     console.log(`${numbers[e]} is odd`);
     // document.querySelector("#odd").innerHTML = numbers[e];
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add your code as text to the question.

Comment: Please don't use images. Please add your code, using the editor provided, to the question.

Comment: PS It looks like you need `forEach(sort)`, and you're not concatenating the text to the existing text on the element, just replacing the text with the new number.

Comment: Looks like you're not using the `e` variable in correct way, as it's not incremented anywhere but it's used as an index of an array. I'd suggest adding HTML content to the question, so it will be easier to figure out if all other places are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Pass sort to forEach, don't call that

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

function sort(e) {
  const type = e % 2 === 0 ? "even" : "odd";
  console.log(`${e} is ${type}`);
}
const no = numbers.forEach(sort);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a for loop and an if statement.

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

function sort() {
  for (let e = 0; e < numbers.length; e++) {
    if (numbers[e] % 2 === 0) {
      console.log(`${numbers[e]} is even`);
      // document.querySelector("#even").innerHTML = numbers[e];
    } else {
      console.log(`${numbers[e]} is odd`);
      // document.querySelector("#odd").innerHTML = numbers[e];
    }
  }
}

sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run it like below so if you wanna check it using the i which is key then remove comment part of if otherwise continue with the same.

```js
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

numbers.forEach((val, i) => sort(i, val));

function sort(i, val) {
  //if(numbers[i] % 2 === 0) {
  if(val % 2 === 0) {
    //console.log(`${numbers[i]} is even`);
    console.log(`${val} is even`);
  } else {
     //console.log(`${numbers[i]} is odd`);
     console.log(`${val} is odd`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

// Cache your elements so you're not
// picking them up in each iteration
const even = document.querySelector("#even");
const odd = document.querySelector("#odd");

// forEach doesn't return anything so
// there's no point assigning it to a variable
// Additionally you should be assigning the reference
// of `sort` as the callback, not the result of
// calling the function
numbers.forEach(sort);

// Make sure you pass in your element to the function
function sort(el) {
  
  // Now just check that element
  if (el % 2 === 0) {
    
    // And I'd recommend using textContent as concatentation
    // with innerHTML reparses the HTML
    // each time which can be a performance hit
    // See link below
    even.textContent += el;
  } else {
    odd.textContent += el;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="even"></div>
<div id="odd"></div>
```

[Why is "element.innerHTML+=" bad code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515383/why-is-element-innerhtml-bad-code#comment15217993_11515395)

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this

```js
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
// Your sort function
function sort(n) {
  if((n % 2) === 0)
    document.querySelector('#even').innerHTML += n + ", ";
  else
    document.querySelector('#odd').innerHTML += n + ", ";
}
// Append numbers to respective element
numbers.forEach(sort);
```

```html
Even: <p id="even"></p>
Odd: <p id="odd"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of problems related to the code. I put comments to your code, so you can check why it does not work.

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

// The initial value for e is not defined so first read from the
// array will look like "numbers[undefined]"
let e;

// The "sort" is called before it's declared, so this might cause
// problems. 
// Also passing callback to the forEach function should look like this
// numbers.forEach(sort). When calling forEach(sort()) you're trying
// to pass a result of the sort() function to forEach which will be 
// undefined.
let no = numbers.forEach(sort());

function sort() {
  // The "e" variable is not initialized and not incremented anywhere
  // so this will not work at all. 
  if(numbers[e] % 2 === 0) {
    console.log(`${numbers[e]} is even`);
    // This piece overwrites content of the HTML tag each time
    // it's called. You need to append to the content.
    
    // document.querySelector("#even").innerHTML = numbers[e];
  } else {
     console.log(`${numbers[e]} is odd`);
    
     // This is affected by the same issue as writing to the 
     // #even tag.

     // document.querySelector("#odd").innerHTML = numbers[e];
  }
}
```

Working solution for your problem might look like this

HTML

```
<div id="even"> Even numbers: </div>
<div id="odd"> Odd numbers: </div>
```

and JavaScript

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

function sort(item) {
    // Here you can check if number is even or odd
    // and decide which HTML element should be updated 
    // in just a single line. 
    let tagId = item % 2 === 0 ? "even" : "odd";

    // And here you just updated HTML tag with extra content
    // by appending next numbers separated by a space. 
    document.getElementById(tagId).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', item + " ");
}

numbers.forEach(sort);
```

Answer (score 0):

Details commented in example.

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

const parity = array => {
  // Make an array of <p>
  const p = [...document.querySelectorAll('p')];
  /*
  Iterate thru given array
  parity check is 0 or 1
  p[0] first <p>
  p[1] second <p>
  */
  array.forEach((num, idx) => {
    let par = num % 2 === 1 || num === 1 ? 1 : 0; 
    p[par].insertAdjacentText('beforeEnd',num+' ');
  });
};

parity(numbers);
```

```html
<p></p>
<p></p>
```