# html Div with javascript numerical widgets

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfKTh.png)

I want to create It dynamically by providing n
n=total number
for example in above image n=30

I want to make it in html, using jquery or javascript
and its not a keypad moreof a counter of how many questions are inserte and how many left.

Comment: Check  jquery plugins:
https://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/Keypad/

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS `grid`:

```js
const widgetContainer = document.getElementById("widget-container");

let n = 30;

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    widgetContainer.innerHTML += "<button>" + i + "</button>";
}
```

```css
div#widget-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, calc(100%/6));
    grid-gap: 5px;
    max-width: 250px;
}

div#widget-container>* {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="widget-container">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi. [Just so you know about the problems with innerHTML concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11515395/1377002).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @Andy. I am aware of the innerHTML problems and XSS vulnerabilities. This was just a demo/proof of concept.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple to do with [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid), and some JavaScript.

Create a function that accepts a number, and loops until that number creating an HTML string on each iteration. It places each string into an array, and then returns the [`joined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) array as a string of HTML.

That HTML string is added to a container that uses Grid to display the HTML.

Since this isn't a keypad you can add a supplementary [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to each element so you can target them separately if you need to.

```js
function createButtons(n) {

  // Create an array
  const html = [];

  // Push HTML into the array on each iteration
  // Each button has its own data id
  // Note: I've used a button here because they're
  // easier to style
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    html.push(`<button data-id="${i}" class="pad" disabled>${i}</button>`);
  }

  // Return the joined-up array as a string
  return html.join('');

}

// Select the container, and add the result
// of calling the function as its innerHTML
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
grid.innerHTML = createButtons(30);

// Set the count, and grab all the buttons
const count = 7;
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.pad');

// Now you can loop over the button collection, and
// add an active class to each button in the loop...
for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  buttons[i].classList.add('active');
}

//...or activate them seperately
const eighteen = document.querySelector('.pad[data-id="18"]');
eighteen.classList.add('active');
```

```css
.grid { display: grid; width: 250px; grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr); row-gap: 0.6em;}
.pad { padding: 0.5em 0.2em; border-radius: 5px; color: red; border: 1px solid red; background-color: white; width: 40px;}
.active { background-color: lightblue; color: black; }
```

```html
<div class="grid"></div>
```