# How do I iterate the array, then show all the elements in HTML?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm learning javascript, I try my best to use correct "word" to describe my question :)
This is my code, now it could only show the last item of the array to HTML, I thought forEach should iterate the while array to get all elements populate to HTML... anyone could give me some suggestion?

```js
const backpackContents = ["piggy", "headlamp", "pen"];
backpackContents.forEach(function (item) {
  document.querySelector("body").innerHTML = `<li>${item}</li>`;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Console demo</title>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: it would be better if you edit your question by providing code, not images!

Comment: Change `.innerHTML = ` to `.innerHTML += `.

Comment: Note: [Why is "element.innerHTML+=" bad code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515383/why-is-element-innerhtml-bad-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `@Rocky Sims` said in comments change `.innerHTML =`  to `.innerHTML +=`

```js
const backpackContents = ["piggy", "headlamp", "pen"];
backpackContents.forEach(function(item) {
  document.querySelector("ul").innerHTML += `<li>${item}</li>`;
})
```

```html
<ul>
</ul>
```