# How do you use Javascript to add or remove HTML/CSS code?

Tags: javascript, html

If I have a bunch of HTML code, similar to the following:

```
<div id='test0div'>
   <p id='test0'></p>
</div>
```

How do I use JavaScript to add or remove more of those - i.e.

```
<div id='test1div'>
   <p id='test1'></p>
</div>
<div id='test2div'>
   <p id='test2'></p>
</div>
```

...etc.?

Comment: MY advice is to use Jquery for this. It simplifies it a lot. You can find a lot of info here: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584751/inserting-html-into-a-div
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566203/changing-css-values-with-javascript

Comment: Learn about DOM manipulation: http://quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html .

Comment: @IvayloToskov w3schools is a bad site and is [looked down on](http://w3fools.com) by SO

Comment: Sort of anticipating some other answers (I saw some stuff on the web, such as addelement/removeelement), how do you control where the elements are inserted?

Comment: @user3550435 - What have you tried? Have you made any attempts to do this or do you just [want teh codez](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/129950)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var container = document.createElement("div");
for(var i=0; i<5; i++) { // change i <5 as per your data source
   var div = document.createElement("div");
   var p = document.createElement("p");
   p.id = "test"+i;
   div.id = "test"+i+"div";
   div.appendChild(p);
   container.appendChild(div); // you can event append to particular id or body    
}

   // document.getElementById("divId").appendChild(container);
```

`container`, will have all the divs & p as you wish
This will give you the output you want. Just change the number of times the loop will execute based on your wish.

Answer (score 0):

To remove you could use

```
$('#id').remove();
```

To add you could use

```
$("<div id='new'></div>").appendTo('#id');
```

Comment: Note that this is not "pure" javascript and requires the jQuery Library. @JordanD you shouldn't assume every one is using jquery, and the question is not tagged with jquery.