# Right way to fill HTML from JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am currently working on a page that requires filling a div programmatically with a bunch of HTML like this sample code

```
<div id="Element">
  <div class="tooltiptext top both">
    <div class="editorMenuButton">
      <span>Editor Menu</span>
      <img src="https://github.com/..." />
    </div>
    <div class="diceButton">
      <img src="https://github.com/..." />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

right now, I am doing this as follows

```
Element.innerHTML = "<div class='tooltiptext top both'><div class='editorMenuButton'><span>Editor Menu</span><img src='https://github.com/...' /></div><div class='diceButton'><img src='https://github.com/...' /></div></div>";
```

which definitely works, but using a string to pass HTML seems like probably not the right/best/professional way to do it. Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add one specific HTML block with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385598/how-to-add-one-specific-html-block-with-jquery)

Comment: i think this is the best way to pass HTML, maybe you need to format string HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without involving any external libraries/frameworks, plain javascript allows you to create elements:

```
var mydiv = document.createElement('div');
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement ]

You can add various properties as needed:

```
mydiv.className = 'tooltiptext top both';
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element

Then append these created elements to other elements

```
Element.appendChild(mydiv);
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append

There are several libraries that make this a bit easier such as [metaflux](https://metaflux.io/docs/overview/)

Answer (score 1):

Well, in some cases make sense to use a string, but if you need something more structured, you may use `document.createElement`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement