# looping through 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, foreach

I am trying to loop through 2 arrays. The first array is the link name the second array is the links 'a' value. I want to loop through the two arrays attaching the value of the second array to the href of each link that is created / in the first array. This is what I have and it not working for me.

```
const links = ['Home', 'Contact', 'About'];
const hrefLinks = ['/', 'contact', 'about'];

for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < hrefLinks.length; i++) {
        if (links.length === hrefLinks.length) {
            const li = document.createElement('li');
            const liLink = document.createElement('a');
            liLink.setAttribute('href', hrefLinks[i]);
            liLink.className = 'Test-Class';
            li.appendChild(liLink);
            li.className = 'nav-link';
            list.appendChild(li);
            li.innerHTML += links[i];
        }
    }
}
```

I do have it working with one forEach loop but got confused on how I would nest the second forEach;

```
const links = ['Home', 'Contact', 'About'];
const hrefLinks = ['/', 'contact', 'about'];

 links.forEach(function (link) {
     const li = document.createElement('li');
     const liLink = document.createElement('a');
     li.appendChild(liLink);
     li.className = 'nav-link';
     list.appendChild(li);
     li.innerHTML += link;
 });
```

Is this the proper way of doing this or is there an easier / cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: Can you make the third sentence in your first paragraph clearer?  State more clearly what you want.

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: @RobertHarvey changed

Comment: @azad No I am not pure Js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want a nested loop - you simply need to link the `i`th item in `links` to the `i`th item of `hrefLinks`. With `forEach`, you can do this just by using the second argument to the callback, which will refer to the current index being iterated over:

```js
const list = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));


const links = ['Home', 'Contact', 'About'];
const hrefLinks = ['/', 'contact', 'about'];

links.forEach((linkName, i) => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = hrefLinks[i];
  a.textContent = linkName;
  li.appendChild(a);
  li.className = 'nav-link';
  list.appendChild(li);
});
```

Comment: _"You don't want a nested loop"_ - Please elaborate on this. Performance wise, `for` loops are much faster than `forEach` loops. So I'd like to know _why_ it should be avoided?

Comment: @icecub There's no need for each `links` item to be used in conjunction with each `hrefLinks` item (`O(N^2)`), so a nested loop doesn't make sense. A nested loop (whether `for` or `forEach`) wouldn't accomplish anything useful. While `for` loops are faster than `forEach` and other array methods, the array methods make for far cleaner code: more functional, automatic abstraction, no need for manual iteration, no hoisting problems (in case the code is in ES5), etc

Comment: @icecub A nested loop would be useful if each item had to do something with each item in the other array, eg here, if one wanted `['Home-/', 'Home-contact', 'Home-about', 'Contact-/', 'Contact-contact', ...]`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't see the bigger picture there so ye, now it makes sense :)

Comment: @icecub it was most likely my poor explanation. I am very noob on all of this still so I don't quite know exactly how to explain things properly

Answer (score 2):

create an objects array which holds the link name and url, then you can iterate that object for add the anchor elements into you dom, as follows

```js
//an object which hold navigation url and name
var navLinks = [{
  label: 'Home',
  href: '/'
}, {
  label: 'Contact',
  href: 'contact'
}, {
  label: 'About',
  href: 'about'
}]

navLinks.forEach(function(link) {

  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.className = 'nav-link';

  var liLink = document.createElement('a');
  var linkText = document.createTextNode(link.label);
  liLink.appendChild(linkText);
  liLink.className = 'Test-Class';
  liLink.href = link.href;

  li.appendChild(liLink);
  document.body.appendChild(li)

});
```

Comment: This is another good way to do it. I will try some thing like this next time. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Replace for-loops by this (we update `document` only once):

```
document.body.innerHTML += links.map( (link,i)=>`
    <li class="nav-link">
        <a class="Test-Class" href="${hrefLinks[i]}">${link}</a>
    </li> 
`).join('');
```

```js
const links = ['Home', 'Contact', 'About'];
const hrefLinks = ['/', 'contact', 'about'];

document.body.innerHTML += links.map( (link,i) =>  `
    <li class="nav-link">
        <a class="Test-Class" href="${hrefLinks[i]}">${link}</a>
    </li> 
`).join('');
```

editable example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/673ywfec/7/). If you need better performance use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51140250/860099). I don't change input data but better approach is when you put href and link in single object like in [azad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53718517/860099) answer, and then use `map`.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use an array of objects except for two arrays?

```js
const anchors = [
  {
    name: 'Home',
    link: '/'
  },
  {
    name: 'Contact',
    link: 'contact'
  },
  {
    name: 'About',
    link: 'about'
  }
];

let ul = document.getElementById('list');

anchors.forEach(function(item) {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  let a = document.createElement('a');
  a.className = 'nav-link';
  a.href = item.link;
  a.innerHTML = item.name;
  li.appendChild(a);
  ul.appendChild(li);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Anchors</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul id="list"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I think this is efficient.

Comment: I honestly didn't even think about using this setup.