# Whats an alternative way for innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a form validation with javascript. I am wondering, instead of `innerHTML` to show my error message are there another way of showing my error message.

Here is the Code:

```
<form>
<p>
Email Address:<br>
<input type="text" id="email-address" name="email" style="width:200px;">
</p>
<p id="my-error-message-container" style="display:none; border:1px solid red; color:red; background-color:yellow; font-weight:bold; padding:5px; width:188px; position: relative;"></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Form" style="width:200px;" onclick="return ErrorCheck()">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function RemoveErrorMessageFromPage()
{
   var IDofContainer = "my-error-message-container";
   document.getElementById(IDofContainer).innerHTML = "";
   document.getElementById(IDofContainer).style.display = "none";
}

function InsertErrorMessageIntoPage(content)
{
   var IDofContainer = "my-error-message-container";
   document.getElementById(IDofContainer).style.display = "";
   document.getElementById(IDofContainer).innerHTML = content;
}

function ErrorCheck()
{
   RemoveErrorMessageFromPage();
   var email = document.getElementById("email-address").value;
   if( ! email.length )
   {
      InsertErrorMessageIntoPage("The email address is required.");
      return false;
   }
   if( ! email.match(/\w@\w+\.\w/) )
   {
      InsertErrorMessageIntoPage("The email address appears to be invalid.");
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can use `innerText` if you don't want it to be interpreted as HTML. That's about it.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: You can remove all elements inside P and then add again using `append`

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach (having an HMTL element for an error message and setting its text and visibility as appropriate when an error occurs / is resolved) is fine. Usually, `textContent` is proffered over `innerHTML` as it's more explicit (you're setting text, not HTML which happens to be text).

The [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Description) for `textContent` actually compares `textContent`, `innerHTML`, and `innerText`, 3 similar attributes.

Answer (score -1):

Here is faster alternative ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51140250/860099))

```js
err.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin','My error message');
```

```css
.err { color: red }
```

```html
<div id="err" class="err"></div>
```