# How to implement for loop inside html template similar to angular,vue

Tags: javascript

i'm very keen in knowing how do `angular,vue` implement for loop inside template.

let say i have data like below, i need to iterate them and append to dom.

```
var list = ['Apple','Banana','Orange'];
var unorderedListTemplate = `<ul>`;
var listTemplate = '';
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    listTemplate += `<li>${list[i]}</li>`;
 }
unorderedListTemplate += listTemplate;
unorderedListTemplate += '</ul>'
console.log('completed list',unorderedListTemplate);
```

In `vuejs` it is implemented like below code

```
 <ul>
  <li v-for="item in list">
    {{ item }}
  </li>
 </ul>
```

How do they achieve the above code, i'm  very interested in knowing.

Very interestingly they are able to keep track of `key` and `value` of object

let say we have data

```
   var objectData = {
          title: 'How to do lists in Vue',
          author: 'Jane Doe',
          publishedAt: '2016-04-10'
   }

 <div v-for="(value, name) in objectData">
  {{ name }}: {{ value }}
</div>
```

**Question**: How can i implement template side for loop similar to vue,angular in `javascript`

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584751/inserting-html-into-a-div

Comment: There is something called template compiler. It is a function that analyse the `template` and calls `render` function with all it's attributes. Here, watch this ⏩ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0pMbM2Q5kI